# C# Prefix Radio Button List Option with Alphabet Character

Tags: c#

I have a collection of objects that bind to a `System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl`:

```
foreach (var answer in SomeCollection)
{
    System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem listItem = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem();
    listItem.Value = answer.ID.ToString();
    listItem.Text = answer.AnswerText;
    listControl.Items.Add(listItem);
}
```

I now want to add a prefix to each answer of "A", "B", "C", "D", etc. So the output would look like:

```
A. Answer 1
B. Answer 2
C. Answer 3
```

The most answers we have is 10 so there is no need to worry about running out of letters. What is the right way to do this?

I have tried the following and it works, however I feel there should be a better way:

```
char[] alphabet = new char[]{ 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G',..., 'Y', 'Z' };

for (int i = 0; i < SomeCollection.Count; i++)
{
    var answer = SomeCollection[i]
    System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem listItem = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem();
    listItem.Value = answer.ID.ToString();
    listItem.Text = alphabet[i] + "." + answer.AnswerText;
    listControl.Items.Add(listItem);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming the main concern is that big character array. The following should also work...

```
char letter = 'A';

for (int i = 0; i < SomeCollection.Count; i++)
{
    var answer = SomeCollection[i]
    System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem listItem = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem();
    listItem.Value = answer.ID.ToString();
    listItem.Text = letter + "." + answer.AnswerText;
    listControl.Items.Add(listItem);
    letter++;
}
```

Comment: That was the concern. I know it works but it just didn't look right when I was typing it. Wasn't sure if I was missing a simple option.

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head, it sounds like you could zip a generated Enum.Range of characters with your collection... something like this, perhaps:

```
    var someCollection = new List<string> {"Item1", "Item2", "Item3"};
    var prefixes = Enumerable.Range('a', 'z' - 'a' + 1).Select(x => (char)x);

    ...

    var items = prefixes.Zip(someCollection, (a,b) => a + " " + b);
```

Doing this, you can just assign the items collection directly to your listControl.

Answer (score 1):

I don't actually have a compiler at hand, but how about something along the lines of this?

```
var charcode = (int)'A';
var items = SomeCollection.Select((answer, index) => new ListItem{
    Value = answer.ID,
    Text = String.Format("{0}.{1}", (char)(charcode+index), answer.AnswerText)
});
```